# EthernetUdp2 does not name a type

Tags: ethernet

I'm using arduino Ethernet shield 2 form arduino.org and the arduino IDE 1.7.10 also from arduino.org 
the code is :

```
#include <Dhcp.h>
#include <Dns.h>
#include <Ethernet2.h>
#include <EthernetClient.h>
#include <EthernetServer.h>
#include <EthernetUdp2.h>
#include <Twitter.h>
#include <util.h>


#include<SPI.h>


EthernetUdp2 udp;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

and it is giving the following Error :

```
Arduino: 1.7.10 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino Uno"

UDPMessages002.ino:14:1: error: 'EthernetUdp2' does not name a type

Error compiling.

  This report would have more information with
  "Show verbose output during compilation"
  enabled in File > Preferences.
```

after Enabling Show verbose output I got :

```
Arduino: 1.7.10 (Windows 8.1), Board: "Arduino Uno"

Build options changed, rebuilding all

Using library Ethernet2 in folder: C:\Program Files\ArduinoOrg\libraries\Ethernet2 

Using library SPI in folder: C:\Program Files\ArduinoOrg\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI 



C:\Program Files\ArduinoOrg/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=107010 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files\ArduinoOrg\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files\ArduinoOrg\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard -IC:\Program Files\ArduinoOrg\libraries\Ethernet2\src -IC:\Program Files\ArduinoOrg\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SPI C:\Users\friend\AppData\Local\Temp\build8617491196975133384.tmp\UDPMessages002.cpp -o C:\Users\friend\AppData\Local\Temp\build8617491196975133384.tmp\UDPMessages002.cpp.o 

UDPMessages002.ino:14:1: error: 'EthernetUdp2' does not name a type

Error compiling.
```

any Help please

These libraries came with the IDE and were not added by me and all the includes 
were added automatically after using Sketch --> Import Library --> Ethernet2

Answer (score 1):

The error you see, `'EthernetUdp2' does not name a type`, means exactly that - there is no type `EthernetUdp2` defined.

If you look at the source of [EthernetUdp2.h](https://github.com/adafruit/Ethernet2/blob/master/src/EthernetUdp2.h), you'll see that the class declaration is `EthernetUDP`. See:

```
class EthernetUDP : public UDP {
    private:
        // Private members...
    public:
        EthernetUDP();  // Constructor

      // Public members...

};
```

`class EthernetUDP : public UDP` defines a class called `EthernetUDP` that inherets from the base class `UDP`. The constructor is what gets called when you instantiate a new object of type `EthernetUDP`.

Replace the line `EthernetUdp2 udp;` in your code with `EthernetUDP udp;` and it should work because the types will match. For reference:

```
#include <Dhcp.h>
#include <Dns.h>
#include <Ethernet2.h>
#include <EthernetClient.h>
#include <EthernetServer.h>
#include <EthernetUdp2.h>
#include <Twitter.h>
#include <util.h>


#include<SPI.h>


EthernetUDP udp; // <---- This works

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: Which one do you mean ?

Comment: class EthernetUDP : public UDP {

Comment: here ? or here : public:
  EthernetUDP();  // Constructor

Comment: The first one. I'll edit to make it more clear.

Comment: but I'm using Ethernet shield 2 not 1

Comment: Right, but the class name is still EthernetUDP in the Ethernet2 library

Answer (score -1):

As it was answered above by Cheirbriados, the library is `EthernetUdp.h` not `EthernetUdp2.h`. I'll post you an example code, but you can also analyze it by yourself, by going on tab Examples of the Arduino IDE and choosing Ethernet -> UDPSendReceiveString:

```
#include <SPI.h>         // needed for Arduino versions later than 0018
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <EthernetUdp.h>         // UDP library from: bjoern@cs.stanford.edu 12/30/2008


// Enter a MAC address and IP address for your controller below.
// The IP address will be dependent on your local network:
byte mac[] = {
  0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 177);

unsigned int localPort = 8888;      // local port to listen on

// buffers for receiving and sending data
char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE];  //buffer to hold incoming packet,
char  ReplyBuffer[] = "acknowledged";       // a string to send back

// An EthernetUDP instance to let us send and receive packets over UDP
EthernetUDP Udp;
```

Comment: That library is for the legacy Ethernet shield. The Ethernet Shield 2 (which the OP has) uses the Ethernet2 library, so your answer is likely incompatible with their hardware.